# Where is the KTX toast extension function?

Tags: android, android-ktx

I have learned from this article Even Sweeter Android development with Android KTX (https://www.kotlindevelopment.com/even-sweeter-android-ktx-kotlin/) that Android toast can be simplified using KTX from

```
Toast.makeText(context, R.string.toast_message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

to

```
toast(R.string.toast_message)
```

I wanted to try it in my project but I couldn't find it in `androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.0`. So in which dependency is this extension function?

Comment: `but i could'nt find` add to app module and rename your xml to be apart of it also androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this

```
api "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-commons:0.10.1"
```

and use it like

```
toast(R.string.toast_message)
```

or

```
context.toast(R.string.toast_message)
```

Comment: latest version is `0.10.8`

Comment: Do I need to keep `androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.0` if I use this one?

Comment: It is safer to use safe call operator(.?) to prepare for the context being null. like `context?.toast(R.string.toast_message)`

Comment: that uses anko. How to use it with kotlin-ktx alone?

Comment: these are their arrangement and I'm also wondering why so
read this https://github.com/Kotlin/anko#anko-coroutines-wiki

Comment: anko is deprecated

Comment: 1. Anko is deprecated
2. The question was about ktx lib

Answer (score 6):

Looks like Context.toast extension was removed from ktx lib
https://github.com/android/android-ktx/issues/143#issuecomment-417891391

Answer (score 2):

You can add a method extension to implement, as far as I know, there is no ready-made.

```
    fun Context.toast(message: String, duration: Int = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT) {
        Toast.makeText(this, message, duration).show()
    }

    fun Context.toast(@StringRes resId: Int, duration: Int = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT) {
       Toast.makeText(this, this.resources.getText(resId), duration).show()
    }
```